# Ajax, PHP and Smarty - spam bot defense mechanism

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty, spam

I am trying to build an anti spam bot mechanism in a form, using a jQuery UI slider along with a honey pot input field. But up to this point we are still receiving spam messages.

At the moment I have the submit button rendering into its parent html using jquery, but if somehow (I don't even know how a bot would be able to accomplish this) slide the slider to its accepted position, the button would still render. I am also changing the submit button's onClick event from "return false" to "return true" if the honey pot's value is empty. I'm basically throwing as many things as I can think of to deter bots, but they're still getting through - or at least I am assuming it is a bot/s since we are getting a lot of spam.

My idea to further the increase the difficulty level to which a bot would need to go through, is to only render the actual submit button once the slider has been shifted to its accepted place, and the honey pot still remains empty. But I would like to do this in the server side...with PHP and/or Smarty (templating language). My train-of-thought is to have a AJAX call made once the slider is in its accepted position (and honey pot empty) to retrieve the button, then have some sort of acceptance pop-up/alert box where the user would click "OK", and only then the button would render. I'm not sure if this would be any different than what I currently have setup, but I am open to suggestions.

My question is, how would I accomplish this? Can AJAX go into a Smarty file and retrieve a variable storing the button? What about with PHP - same question, can AJAX dip into a PHP file and retrieve the button variable? And would you guys think this would yield any better results from what I currently have?

Thank you all for any feedback!

```js
$("#tst-verify-slider").draggable({
      axis: 'x',
      containment: 'parent',
      drag: function(event, ui) {
         var hp = $('#tst-verify-check').val(),
            btn = '<button class="button" type="submit" title="Submit" onclick="return false;">Submit</button>';
         if ( hp == '' ) {
            if (ui.position.left > 235) {
               $(this).animate({
                  left: 237
               }, 1);
               $('.tst-verify-submit').html(btn).attr('onClick', 'return true;');
            }
         } else {
            alert('HELL NO SON!');
            return false;
         }
      },
      stop: function(event, ui) {
         if (ui.position.left < 234) {
            $(this).animate({
               left: 2
            }, 1);
            $('.tst-verify-submit').html('').attr('onClick', 'return false;');
         }
      }
   });

   $('.tst-verify-submit button').click(function(){
      var hp = $('#tst-verify-check').val();
      if ( hp != '' ) {
         alert('HELL NO SON!');
         return false;
      }
   });
```

```css
#tst-verify-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#tst-verify-wrapper, .tst-verify-submit {
    padding: 0 0 0 170px;
}

#tst-verify-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 12px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

#tst-verify-container #tst-verify-slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 61px;
    height: 61px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #db0b0b;
    border-radius: 9px;
    left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#tst-verify-container p {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 65px;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- SLIDER DIVS -->
<div id="tst-verify-wrapper">
     <div id="tst-verify-container">
      <div id="tst-verify-slider">
      </div>
      <p>Slide to Continue. <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="tst-verify-check" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" required>
</div>

<!-- HONEY POT INPUT FIELD -->
<input type="hidden" id="tst-verify-check" placeholder="Phone Number" value="asdasd" required>

<!-- SUBMIT BUTTON PARENT DIV -->
<div class="tst-verify-submit"></div>

<!-- ORIGINAL SMARTY VAR RENDERING THE SUBMIT BUTTON -->
<!-- I REMOVED IT AND HAVE THE RAW HTML IN A JS VAR -->
<!--
      <div class="tst-verify-submit">  {$submit_button} </div>
-->
```

Comment: Using something like recaptcha is a lot easier

Comment: We did, spam was still being sent through.

Comment: If implemented correctly, it should reduce the spam. If the spam got through, must be a very advance bot or just human. A bot just need to simulate the request made to the server, they dont need to look at the html page. Even the ajax request you mention can be simulated, because it is just a http request